# Django cannot detect GeoIP data from nginx

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, geoip

I am trying to get the country_code from people that visit my site, i decided to use `nginx geoIP` module to do this. I already set the `nginx` configurations, etc etc. But somehow it always keeps giving empty values. The `nginx` have `--with-http_geoip_module` when i used `nginx -V`, so it's `GeoIP` function should work. I am using `uwsgi` for my `django`.

I already installed the geoIP datas with:

```
cd /etc/nginx/geoip
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz
gunzip GeoIP.dat.gz
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
```

This is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 210;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    geoip_country /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat; # the country IP database
    geoip_city /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat; # the city IP database

    proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_country_code3;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_city_country_code;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_city_country_code3;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_city_country_name;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_REGION $geoip_region;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_CITY $geoip_city;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE $geoip_postal_code;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_CITY_CONTINENT_CODE $geoip_city_continent_code;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_LATITUDE $geoip_latitude;
    proxy_set_header GEOIP_LONGITUDE $geoip_longitude;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This is my /etc/nginx/sites-available:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name www.testname.com testname.com;

access_log  off;
error_log  /var/www/log_nginx/error.log;   
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

client_header_timeout 180s;
client_body_timeout 180s;
client_max_body_size 100m;

proxy_connect_timeout   120s;
proxy_send_timeout      180s;
proxy_read_timeout      180s;
send_timeout            600s;

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

location /static {    
    alias /var/www/test_project/static;    
}

location /media {    
   alias /var/www/test_project/media_root;    
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HTTP_X_GEOIP_COUNTRY $geoip_country_name;
    proxy_set_header HTTP_X_GEOIP_CITY    $geoip_city;
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 500;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 500;
    uwsgi_pass      unix:/var/www/testproject_global.sock;
   }

}
```

This is my uwsgi_params:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;
uwsgi_param HTTP_X_GEOIP_COUNTRY $geoip_country_code;
uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_country_code3;

uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_city_country_code;
uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_city_country_code3;
uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_city_country_name;
uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_REGION $geoip_region;
uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_CITY $geoip_city;
uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE $geoip_postal_code;
uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_CITY_CONTINENT_CODE $geoip_city_continent_code;
uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_LATITUDE $geoip_latitude;
uwsgi_param HTTP_GEOIP_LONGITUDE $geoip_longitude;
```

I already set GeoIP.dat and GeoLiteCity.dat in /etc/nginx/geoip/

But when i tried to fetch the data in my Django with:

```
keys_with_values = ''.join("%s=%r <br />" % (key, val) for (key, val) in request.META.iteritems())
```

It always returns empty value, like the following:

```
HTTP_X_GEOIP_COUNTRY='' 
HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME='' 
# etc etc
```

Comment: any help would be great :(

Answer (score 0):

Some of your `proxy_set_header` header names are badly formatted but that's not your problem here because you aren't actually doing any proxying, there is no `proxy_pass` directive.

The `uwsgi param` directive sets headers to be passed by `uwsgi_pass`. Your Nginx directives look correct (although best practice would see you prefix your custom headers with X_), the problem is [cgi headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1) and [http headers](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) have different protocols.

So if your Nginx directive says this:

```
uwsgi_param HTTP_X_GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_city_country_code;
```

Then your HTTP header would look like this:

```
X-Geoip-City-Country-Code: xyz
```

Comment: where should i put this "proxy_pass"?